# GKE Disk Utilization Monitoring/Alerting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, diskspace, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I've run into some disk pressure issues under GKE (too many job pods that weren't cleaned up) and I want to somehow be alerted next time I run low on disk space. I looked in Stackdriver Monitoring, but I only see disk read/write bytes/operations. In order to get disk usage/utilization, I think I have to install the stackdriver agent, but I'm not sure if this is possible under GKE. Is there some way to monitor disk utilization for GKE nodes?

Answer (score 2):

when installing the [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing) Agent, there are per default only these two disk metrics available: `container/disk/bytes_total` and `container/disk/bytes_used`. in fact, one cannot really monitor the disk utilization alike that.

rather see [Creating Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics), with an [Alerting Policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/).

Answer (score 2):

Was searching for this today.
The recommended answer relates to a legacy metric.
Now the following metric is available: *metric.type="kubernetes.io/node/ephemeral_storage/allocatable_bytes" resource.type="k8s_node"*